# Weired behavior with Spring REST Template

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

This is my request class

```
    public class TestRequest implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String vendorID = null;
    private String transactionID = null;
    @JsonProperty("TESTAction")
    private String TESTAction = null;

    public String getVendorID() {
        return vendorID;
    }
    public void setVendorID(String vendorID) {
        this.vendorID = vendorID;
    }

    public String getTransactionID() {
    return transactionID;
  }

  public void setTransactionID(String transactionID) {
    this.transactionID = transactionID;
  }

    public String getTESTAction() {
        return TESTAction;
    }

    public void setTESTAction(String TESTAction) {
        TESTAction = TESTAction;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TestStatus [vendorID=" + vendorID + ", transactionID=" + transactionID + ", s TESTAction=" + TESTAction + "]";
    }
}
```

This is my service class

```
HttpEntity<TestRequest > requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(request, headers);
        try {
            LOG.info("Calling REST: " + restUrl);
            responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(restUrl, requestEntity, TestResponseResponse.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Exception in sending data: " + request);
            LOG.error("Exception in sending data to ESL" + e);
            throw new TestRestException("Exception while calling rest service", e);
        }
```

The rest call is working fine as expected but the problem is the third parameter in the request object is sent twice eg:

```
{
"vendorID": "testvendor",
"transactionID" : "testtrans",
"TESTAction": "test action",
"testaction":"test action"
}
```

The last parameter is sent twice in all small characters

Comment: Is there a method getTestaction() implemented?

Comment: This is the problem with request... not a problem with handling request

Comment: Can you post the full `TestRequest` class.

Comment: added full req class

Comment: Respect the Java naming conventions, and everything will always work better. Rename the field `testAction`, and the getter/setter `getTestAction()/setTestAction()`

Comment: @jbNizet you mean to say just change it in java and do not change the @JsonProperty?

Comment: Yes, if you absolutely want to keep the ugly name in the JSON.

Comment: @jbnizet The solution worked. If you provide the comment as an answer I can accept it in stack overflow. But still I am not understanding why spring create an unintended parameter by itself and send. Weired issue it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by using the correct java naming conventions for my getters and setters.

*Its still weired why Spring is so tightly coupled with the naming
 conventions though.*